# Drupal content print by parts

Tags: drupal

I create a content type with fields title header and body and in the page.tpl I want to print in only the header because I have a css that make the header in a box i tried with render($content['header']);
but is not working

Comment: what's not working? the header not showing up? or everything shows up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok well i finish with this I made a tpl.php for every node i wanted to edit and in drupal 7 i have to put hidden($content[`heder`]) or whatever the name of the file in the node is and after print the content for that node I kept the different modifications in variables and I print the variables